# PHP If / Elseif Statement Not Working Correctly

Tags: php

I have a simple if statement that works on my local machine but when i uploaded it tom ypaid site i got an error on my home page.

Error:

```
Warning: include(./pages/.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a5410474/public_html/index.php on line 33
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening './pages/.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a5410474/public_html/index.php on line 33
```

The Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != NULL || $_GET['p'] != '') {
        $p = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
    }elseif ($_GET['p'] == '' || $_GET['p'] == NULL){
        $p = 'home';
    }
include("./pages/".$p.".php");
?>
```

Comment: You will want to filter the `$p` variable to make sure it doesn't include something like `../../../../usr/share/php/something`. You probably only want letters.  An even better approach is to keep an array of valid files that actually exist in `./pages` and check the input value against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much less verbose way of writing this:

```
$p = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];
include("./pages/{$p}.php");
```

Some other notes:

1. You should not be using `mysql_real_escape_string` on a variable you're going to pass to `include`. That function is for preparing data for insertion into a SQL query.
2. You should not `include` a file based on a variable passed through the query string, or from any kind of user input. Someone can use that to read system files on your server then take control of the whole computer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of OR, you need AND here, also enclose the second half in parens.

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != NULL || $_GET['p'] != '') {

// should be
if (isset($_GET['p']) && ($_GET['p'] != NULL && $_GET['p'] != '')) {
```

You have no `else` case, and it's likely the value being passed into `$_GET['p'] meets neither condition.

It would be better to write it like this, using `empty()`

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p']) {
  $p = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
}
else $p = 'home';
```

Comment: You do not need to use both `isset` and `empty`, as `empty` calls `isset` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more aware of directory traversing, sanitize user input, and make sure the file is even there. (re: your errors):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s', '', $_GET['p']);
} else {
    $p = 'home';
}
$path = "./pages/" . $p . ".php";

if (file_exists($path) === true) {
    include $path;
} else {
    include './pages/notfound.php';
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it threw off my layout somehow... didnt work.

Comment: in your pages eg: home.php are you including raw html or php that echos any html or are you enclosing output within a variable?

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this:

```
<?php
    $p = 'home';
    if (!empty($_GET['p']))
        $p = $_GET['p'];       
    include("./pages/".$p.".php")
?>
```